# Proxy redirecting websockets and http to the same (unix) socket

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, websocket, daphne

I've made a little nginx conf to redirect trafic to a unix socket listened by a `daphne` server (server used for `django`).

According to the [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html#run-interface-servers) :

> If you use Daphne for all traffic, it auto-negotiates between HTTP and
>   WebSocket, so there’s no need to have your WebSockets on a separate
>   port or path

**So I'd like to proxy both websockets and Http trafic to the same unix socket.**

1. Is it possible?
2. How could I do?

Here is what I tried thus far :

```
upstream django_ws {
         server unix:///path/to/ws.sock;
}

server {
       listen 8082;
       server_name 127.0.0.1;
       charset utf-8;

       root /path/to/root;

       set $myroot $document_root;

       location / {
                proxy_pass http://django_ws;
                #proxy_http_version 1.1;
                #proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
                #proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
       }
}
```

- If I uncomment the lines in the location bloc, the page appears blank.
- If I don't, the pages appear but the websockets don't seem to work.

How could I solve this?

Everything works fine with the development server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

I instanciate my websockets like this :

```
var socket = new WebSocket(ws_scheme + "://" + window.location.host
                           + "/ws" + window.location.pathname);
```

So I can just separate request coming to `/ws` and requests coming to `/`.

So I just did this :

```
upstream django_ws {
         server unix:///path/to/ws.sock;
}

server {
       listen 8082;
       server_name 127.0.0.1;
       charset utf-8;

       root /path/to/root;

       set $myroot $document_root;


       location /ws {
                proxy_pass http://django_ws;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
                proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
       }

       location / {
                proxy_pass http://django_ws;
       }
}
```

and it worked just fine!